# Compiling apps for Zedboard Zynq-7000

Tags: c++, compilation, sdk, zynq

It it possible to compile C++ applications for bare metal Zedboard Zynq-7000 without Xilinx Vitis huge stuff? I just want to check whether some C++ libraries use compatible language features.

Comment: The zynq-7000 has two arm cortex A9 cores. You can use the arm cross compiler to check your code without installing Vitis.

Answer (score 0):

yes.

The arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc toolchain works just fine. To actually execute the code on bare metal, there is an initial boot sequence which needs to be implemented (FSBL,...)